# Converting the value from string to integer in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-3.x, integer

I want to change the numbers in my dictionary to int values for use later in my program.
So far I have

```
import time
import math
x = 400
y = 300
def read_next_object(file):    
        obj = {}               
        for line in file:      
                if not line.strip(): continue
                line = line.strip()                        
                key, val = line.split(": ")                
                if key in obj and key == "Object": 
                        yield obj                       
                        obj = {}                              
                obj[key] = val

        yield obj              

planets = {}                   
with open( "smallsolar.txt", 'r') as f:
        for obj in read_next_object(f): 
                planets[obj["Object"]] = obj    

print(planets)                

scale=250/int(max([planets[x]["Orbital Radius"] for x in planets if "Orbital Radius" in planets[x]]))
print(scale)
```

and the output is

```
{'Sun': {'Object': 'Sun', 'Satellites': 'Mercury,Venus,Earth,Mars,Jupiter,Saturn,Uranus,Neptune,Ceres,Pluto,Haumea,Makemake,Eris', 'Orbital Radius': '0', 'RootObject': 'Sun', 'Radius': '20890260'}, 'Moon': {'Object': 'Moon', 'Orbital Radius': '18128500', 'Period': '27.321582', 'Radius': '1737000.10'}, 'Earth': {'Object': 'Earth', 'Satellites': 'Moon', 'Orbital Radius': '77098290', 'Period': '365.256363004', 'Radius': '6371000.0'}}
3.2426140709476178e-06
```

I want to be able to convert the numbers in the dict to ints for further use. Any help in greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exact duplicate of your last question! You need start upvoting and accepting! Your getting code from one question and pasting into the next.. might help if you actually tried to do some studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on Chris' answer,

```
>>> myDict = {'Sun': {'Object': 'Sun', 'Satellites': 'Mercury,Venus,Earth,Mars,Jupiter,Saturn,Uranus,Neptune,Ceres,Pluto,Haumea,Makemake,Eris', 'Orbital Radius': '0', 'RootObject': 'Sun', 'Radius': '20890260'}, 'Moon': {'Object': 'Moon', 'Orbital Radius': '18128500', 'Period': '27.321582', 'Radius': '1737000.10'}, 'Earth': {'Object': 'Earth', 'Satellites': 'Moon', 'Orbital Radius': '77098290', 'Period': '365.256363004', 'Radius': '6371000.0'}}
>>> for body in myDict:
...      myDict[body]['Radius'] = float(myDict[body]['Radius'])
...      myDict[body]['Orbital Radius'] = float(myDict[body]['Orbital Radius'])
>>> myDict
13: {'Earth': {'Object': 'Earth',
           'Orbital Radius': 77098290.0,
           'Period': '365.256363004',
           'Radius': 6371000.0,
           'Satellites': 'Moon'},
 'Moon': {'Object': 'Moon',
          'Orbital Radius': 18128500.0,
          'Period': '27.321582',
          'Radius': 1737000.1},
 'Sun': {'Object': 'Sun',
         'Orbital Radius': 0.0,
         'Radius': 20890260.0,
         'RootObject': 'Sun',
         'Satellites': 'Mercury,Venus,Earth,Mars,Jupiter,Saturn,Uranus,Neptune,Ceres,Pluto,Haumea,Makemake,Eris'}}
```

Comment: i have one question when adding this line of code planets[body]['Period'] = float(planets[body]['Period'])

Comment: to change the period to floats i get an error      KeyError: 'Period'

Comment: That is because `Sun` doesn't have a `Period` key. So you'll have to write an if statement. `if "Period" in myDict[body]:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast them.  For some value `x`, you can cast it as an integer with `int(x)`.

I also notice that some of your values are floating point values.  If you wish to keep them as floating point values (with decimals), you can use `float(x)`.

Comment: how would that work i want to iterate over to dict not create any new lists or dicts

Comment: `value_as_integer = int(planets["mykey"])`